# Why are some ads on Stack Overflow not written in English?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I wonder why some ads on Stack Overflow are not written in English, in spite of the only supported language on the site is English.

[image]

Comment: It's for a job in Israel. Why shouldn't it be written in Hebrew?

Comment: I would prefer to see everything in the site in English for let everyone can understand everything in the site even the ads.

Comment: Note: That's a translation company.

Comment: I guess it take into account your location. As you chose to write "Online" as your location, it's considered blank so it will take data of any location - if you'll update your account with your real location it might prevent showing you careers from other locations. USA for example is enough, you don't have to give your full address.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Are you sure the ads is filtered upon the location ? I mean if I set my location to France I'll not see this advertisement ?

Comment: @Homam not sure, I started the comment by "I guess" - it just make sense. EDIT: quick look in the careers posted to *me* bring bad news... although I do have valid location it show careers from far far away. So bottom line is what JohnP said in the answer.

Comment: @Homam perhaps one of the primary requirements they have for a candidate is that they speak Hebrew.

Answer (score 12):

That's not advertising (not strictly anyway). Those are job listings from Careers. Since careers can be used by anyone, some people would post in their native language. I suppose it acts as a first level filter in itself. If the job listing is in Hebrew, you don't need to specifically state that Hebrew is needed.

Comment: but it stills goes against the norm that the whole site must be in english. This can harm the community in weird ways, for example, people stop to report spam in russian because they just think it's a job post in moscow.

Comment: But that kind of content only appears in the ad areas. It's in a specified ad area, it doesn't come under the content rules of the site. SO is just cross promoting So Careers.

Answer (score 10):

Those are job listings from Careers 2.0. They are targeted to users based on location and tags to make them as relevant as possible. Because the location tagging is imprecise, you may sometimes see job listings from nearby countries where a different language is spoken.